# Swift - Image rotation in degrees - deformed result

Tags: ios, swift, image, rotation, uigraphicscontext

I found several methods to rotate image by degrees in Swift but noone that works allright all the time. I want to rotate image by 90 degrees left or right. I think the best one is this:

```
  class func imageRotated(_ oldImage: UIImage, byDegrees degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    //Calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: oldImage.size.width, height: oldImage.size.height))
    let t: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degrees * CGFloat(M_PI / 180))
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize: CGSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size
    //Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    //Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2, y: rotatedSize.height / 2)
    //Rotate the image context
    bitmap.rotate(by: (degrees * CGFloat(M_PI / 180)))
    //Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    bitmap.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    bitmap.draw(oldImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -oldImage.size.width / 2, y: -oldImage.size.height / 2, width: oldImage.size.width, height: oldImage.size.height))
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
  }
```

It works and do what I want but there are few times when it deformes result so it's not rotated and just image size is changed or it's rotated by 180 degrees and image size is changed.

Before rotation:

[image: Image before rotation]

Afteer rotation (menu is missing because it's automatically hidden):

[image: Image after rotation]

What's weird is that this happens when I take photo in portrait. When I take photo in landscape the rotation works fine (even if I try to rotate several times and even if I rotate from landscape to portrait and than again to landscape, it's still works fine).

I saw some discussion about auto layout constraints problem but I am not sure if it's my problem and why it would for some cases work and for some won't. I have photos in collection cells and each cell has first UIScrollView and than in UIScrollView there is UIImageView with photo. All constraints are set to bounds.

If it helps I want only rotate by 90 or -90 degrees. This could maybe make method more simple andn fix easier.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try to use
self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

Comment: @tejas The question is not about rotating `UIImageView`, but rather `UIImage` itself

Comment: @Libor Please show how you're using this method and double check `contentMode` of your `imageView`. It seems like it is `ScaleToFill`, which assumes distortion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the easiest and probably the best way is to create a view, put an image view on it, rotate the image view, resize the superview and create a screenshot of that view.

You do not actually add these views in the view hierarchy, you just use them to easily generate an image.

Why this is a good procedure is because the `UIView` already has all the code written in it to fully support the core graphics. So there is no downside at all and you can be sure these procedures have already been polished by Apple.

So try this:

```
    func transformImage(image: UIImage?, transform: CGAffineTransform) -> UIImage? {

        guard let image = image else {
            return nil
        }

        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.transform = transform
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: imageView.frame.size.height)


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        if let cgImage = newImage?.cgImage {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        } else {
            return nil
        }

    }
```

As for issue in your procedure it is most likely because you discard the transform from the `UIImage`. The `CGImage` is basically a raw image representation and it has no idea about the rotations. The `UIImage` does have `imageOrientation` though. So what you would need to do to fix that is you need to generate the transformation matrix from the image orientation and use it.

So when you take an image with your device the `CGImage` will always have the same orientation (landscape left or right). But the `UIImage` will change the image orientation which is then used for representation.

Comment: @LiborZapletal I hope you understand where your issue is though. Try taking a photo in portrait and check the size of the UIImage and the size of the CGImage. They will not be the same as the CGImage is still in landscape while the UIImage includes the info that it needs to be rotated and gives you the portrait size.

Comment: Yes, it helps me too. I was thinking that probably something like this would be issue. But I wasn't sure where the problem is and how can I fix it. With your solution it's much easier and looks no performance degradation.

Comment: Well in some cases you still might need to do this manually. What this means is creating a switch statement for UIImage orientation for all 8 cases (yes, there is 8 of them due to mirroring for front camera). Anyway for half of them you need to swap the width and height of the context and for 6 of them you need to use an extra transformation matrix. I usually go with trial-and-error procedure in those cases. So if you can do it with the views then use that procedure, it is even great for resizing, using fit, fill... And it should work on a background thread as well.